# Amazon Advertising API - EditorialReviews sometimes returns null even if it should not for given ISBN

Tags: c#, api, isbn, amazon-advertising-api

I’m  using Amazon Product Advertising API to get data about books based on given ISBN number. It works fine I’m getting most of the information but for some of the books I have a problem with Editorial Reviews. It looks like the information is available on the Amazon web site but I’m not getting it back with my query. Does anyone know why? Below is sample of my code. The sample ISBN may be 9780752809069.
Thanks for any sugestions.

```
            AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient amazonClient;

        amazonClient = new AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient(
        new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), new EndpointAddress("https://ecs.amazonaws.co.uk/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService"));       //Amazon UK working

        amazonClient.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new AmazonSigningEndpointBehavior("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"));

        ItemLookup itemLookup = new ItemLookup();
        ItemLookupRequest request_isbn = new ItemLookupRequest();
        request_isbn.ResponseGroup = new string[] {"EditorialReview", "Large" };
        request_isbn.SearchIndex = "Books";

        request_isbn.ItemId = new string[] { "9780752809069" }; 

        request_isbn.IncludeReviewsSummary = "True";
        request_isbn.IdType = ItemLookupRequestIdType.ISBN;
        request_isbn.IdTypeSpecified = true;


        itemLookup.Request = new ItemLookupRequest[] { request_isbn };
        itemLookup.AssociateTag = "my astag";

        ItemLookupResponse response_isbn = new ItemLookupResponse();

            response_isbn = amazonClient.ItemLookup(itemLookup);



        string _Description = "";  
        foreach (var revitem in response_isbn.Items[0].Item)
          {

              if (revitem.EditorialReviews != null) _Description = revitem.EditorialReviews.Last().Content.ToString(); //Sometimes is null even if there is Product Description avaliable on the Amazon Web

          }
```

Comment: This would be better directed towards somebody at Amazon I would imagine.  One question I have is if ALL editoral comments are acting the same way.

Comment: no, some of them are returned correctly by ItemLookupResponse

Answer (score 0):

ItemLookup does not return some editorial reviews.  ItemLookup only returns the editorial reviews written by Amazon.com Editorial reviews recorded by another website cannot be included in the reviews returned by ItemLookup.

https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Product-Advertising-API/2666